# Call A C# Web Service From PHP Client

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I have this ASP.Net C# Web Service
http://www.emadbook.com/TestWebService/Convert.asmx

and this is the PHP client code:

```
    <?php
        //Use C# Web Service:
        require "lib/nusoap.php";
        $client2 = new nusoap_client("http://www.emadbook.com/TestWebService/Convert.asmx?WSDL","http://tempuri.org/");
        $result = $client2->call("CelsiusToFahrenheit", array(37));
        echo $result;
    ?>
```

this code return nothing and no errors anybody can modify my code to return a value, I think the main error is in passing a number to the service as I looked on google but I could not find a way of sending number parameter?

Edit:
I saw this link:
[Call asp.net web service from PHP with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711502/call-asp-net-web-service-from-php-with-multiple-parameters)
and I modified my code to:

```
<?php
    //Use C# Web Service:
    $client2 = new SoapClient("http://www.emadbook.com/TestWebService/Convert.asmx?WSDL");
    $params->Celsius = '37';   
    $result = $client2->CelsiusToFahrenheit($params)->CelsiusToFahrenheitResult;
    echo (string)$result;
?>
```

and it return a result but before that it show this error:
Warning: Creating default object from empty value
pointing to the Params variable creation, so this is good progress but any body can solve the generated error?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call asp.net web service from PHP with multiple parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711502/call-asp-net-web-service-from-php-with-multiple-parameters)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call web services using soap in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118839/how-to-call-web-services-using-soap-in-php)

Comment: @TZHX Don't take me wrong, but we should not suggest duplicates that have not been answered. Your link post is unsolved (at least it's not marked as answered by OP).

Comment: no it is not solved and my question is unique

Comment: @vnikhil it has an upvoted answer that seems to work well enough -- but I agree your suggestion fits better.

Comment: no it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right Answer I found it by myself and I like to share it for other developers

```
<?php
    //Use C# Web Service:
    $client2 = new SoapClient("http://www.emadbook.com/TestWebService/Convert.asmx?WSDL");
    $params = new ArrayObject();
    $params->Celsius = 37;
    $result = $client2->CelsiusToFahrenheit($params)->CelsiusToFahrenheitResult;
    echo $result;
?>
```