# Brandbank API PHP Extract Data

Tags: php, api, soap, soap-client

I am working on a project that requires access to Brandbank API, however their documentation seems pretty limited as to how to access their information.

I have been given access keys and the documentation seems to direct you to extract data via SOAP siting this link https://api.brandbank.com/svc/feed/extractdata.asmx?WSDL

Can anyone provide an example of how to access the product feed of this API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118839/how-to-call-web-services-using-soap-in-php

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you will need code that looks like this:

```
$wsdl = "https://api.brandbank.com/svc/feed/extractdata.asmx?WSDL";

try {
  $soapclient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
      'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_1,
      'trace' => 1,
      'exceptions' => true,
    )
  );

  $parameters = new stdClass();
  $response = $soapclient->GetUnsentProductData($parameters);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  var_dump($e ->getMessage());
}
```

The call won't work until you finish it with your access credentials, but it provides an example of how most SOAP calls look in PHP.

Comment: please give a favor, how i can pass ExternalCallerId in above code??